# DataTables Net, No data available in table, while a Valid JSON is Provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I will appreciate your help to understand why DataTables returns No data available in table. The JSON endpoint is at https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1YFDhlGve0L7tYjYx6WVOPVUA5eIo9lMJfWrKXyU1hAI/1/public/values?alt=json

The code I used:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
    />

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      charset="utf8"
      src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>myid</th>
          <th>myname</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>myid</th>
          <th>myname</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#example").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url:
            "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1YFDhlGve0L7tYjYx6WVOPVUA5eIo9lMJfWrKXyU1hAI/1/public/values?alt=json",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          dataSrc: function (json) {
            interim_ = json.feed.entry;
            let rows = [];
            for (const i of interim_) {
              let row_ = [i.gsx$myid.$t, i.gsx$myname.$t];
              console.log(row_);
              rows.push(row_);
            }
            let final_ = { data: rows };
            console.log(final_);
            return final_;
          },
        },
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `dataType: "jsonp"` The response is plain JSON, not JSONP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `final_` object is not in the correct format for data tables to recognise.

A simple array will suffice.

Change to `return rows`;

Regarding `json` vs `jsonp` - the data source is `json`, but jquery is intelligent enough that using `dataType: "jsonp"` will also allow `json`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#example").DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1YFDhlGve0L7tYjYx6WVOPVUA5eIo9lMJfWrKXyU1hAI/1/public/values?alt=json",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      dataSrc: function(json) {
        interim_ = json.feed.entry;
        let rows = [];
        for (const i of interim_) {
          let row_ = [i.gsx$myid.$t, i.gsx$myname.$t];
          console.log(row_);
          rows.push(row_);
        }
        //let final_ = {
        //  data: rows
        //};
        //console.log(final_);
        return rows;
      },
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>myid</th>
      <th>myname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>myid</th>
      <th>myname</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: You are awesome @freedomn-m!!! Thank you so much. Both of your recommendations are well accepted and my datatables are now rendering data. The examples in https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html are confusing by showing the `data` property all the time. The reason I used `jsonp` originally was to fix CORS error and interestingly today `json` works just fine :)

Comment: I've had a look through the examples.  It's a little confusing.  Essentially if your data comes back from the server as `{ "mydata": [ ...` then you set `dataSrc: "mydata"` - but you're using `dataSrc` with a function to reformat the data, so there's no sub-property to reference.  Can't link directly: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax  `dataSrc` *As a function it takes a single parameter, the JSON returned from the server, which can be manipulated as required. The returned value from the function is what will be used by DataTables as the data source for the table.*